# Is it really needed to use Spring Data JPA Named Queries?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

After making some search on the web, I think that when using Spring Data JPA Named Queries, we need some extra implementation or definitions comparing to the derived or dynamic queries in Spring Data JPA. In this scene, I am really wondering that do we really need to use Spring Data JPA Named Queries?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data derived queries are intended (and useful) only for very simple queries. Those queries where you look at the name that you would naturally give such a method and would immediately know how to implement it in SQL or JPQL.

As soon as a query gets a little more complex we shouldn't use derived queries anymore, and often we can't even if we wanted to. For example query derivation doesn't have a way to control the precedence between `AND` and `OR`.

For all other queries we need to explicitly code the query one way or the others. And if you don't want your queries mixed with your repository, a named query is a very viable alternative.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. **#1** But is it bad to use both of them in the same project?   **#2.** Could you give an example regarding to the way you use named query? Do you add some setting or notation to application.properties?

Comment: #1 It's not at all bad. It is the expected way to do things. #2 https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-named-queries/